# Printing list of numbers as an array from for loop Python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

With the code below, it prints the value 'phase' one by one. I am trying to print these values as an array outside of for loop.

```
import math

Period = 6.2

time1 = datafile1[:,0]
magnitude1 = datafile1[:,1]
for i in range(len(time1)):
   print(i,time1[i])
   floor = math.floor((time1[i]-time1[0])/Period)
   phase = ((time1[i]-time1[0])/Period)-floor 
   print (phase)
```

It is printing like this:

```
0.002
0.003
0.004
0.005
```

I would like it to print like this:

```
[0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005]
```

Comment: you could append them to a list and print the list

Comment: Please post your `datafile1` structure so answerers can offer working and complete code.

Comment: Add your phases to a list and do something like: `print('[' + ', '.join(phases) + ']')`

Comment: just take an empty list and append the elements one by one in it by the same for loop .

Answer (score 2):

This would be the least modification requirement path to that result

```
result = []

time1 = datafile1[:,0]
magnitude1 = datafile1[:,1]
for i in range(len(time1)):
   result.append(i,time1[i])
   floor = math.floor((time1[i]-time1[0])/Period)
   phase = ((time1[i]-time1[0])/Period)-floor 
   result.append(phase)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I've made it so instead of `printing` your results, you append them to a list, then print out the full list.

```
import math

Period = 6.2

time1 = datafile1[:,0]
magnitude1 = datafile1[:,1]

my_list = []
for i in range(len(time1)):
   my_list.append(i,time1[i])
   floor = math.floor((time1[i]-time1[0])/Period)
   phase = ((time1[i]-time1[0])/Period)-floor 
   my_list.append(phase)

print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
import math

Period = 6.2

time1 = datafile1[:,0]
magnitude1 = datafile1[:,1]
list_to_print = []
for i in range(len(time1)):
   print(i,time1[i])
   floor = math.floor((time1[i]-time1[0])/Period)
   phase = ((time1[i]-time1[0])/Period)-floor
   list_to_print.append(phase)
print (list_to_print)
```